# mysql - locking rows while running transaction

Tags: mysql

I have a transaction which takes a while to complete. I want to protect the affected rows from being updated from outside the current transaction

What is the best practice to do so?

First it would be good if other queries outside the transaction still can read the rows so my application doesn't do a complete hold while doing the work.

When the transaction starts I will change/update a value in one column in each row so it will make a write lock right? Other queries outside of the current transaction can still read the rows (I don't care if old or new values are fetched), but not write to them?

When the current transaction is complete the write lock is freed and other queries can write to the rows again?

Is this the best practice or is there a better way?

I use InnoDB engine for all tables

Comment: Look at `Lock Tables`.

Comment: How much a transaction shall see from (and in turn potentially block) another transaction (including single queries) is specified by your [isolation level](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html). If MySQL cannot guarantee that, it will wait or rollback. While your description generally sounds like the default behaviour (`REPEATABLE READ`), the devil is in the detail (e.g. *queries outside the transaction still can read the rows* can mean old or new values). But to address every detail basically means quoting the manual.

Comment: @Solarflare, if an outside transaction reads old or new values doesn't matter.. I just want to avoid that the affected rows is completely locked from any reads

Comment: If you do not care for the details, I guess that the default behaviour is probably what you are looking for; it will behave pretty much as you described, while preventing inconsistent situation that you probably do not want to think about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT ... FOR SHARE` could be what you are looking for. From the [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html):

> Sets a shared mode lock on any rows that are read. Other sessions can read the rows, but cannot modify them until your transaction commits. If any of these rows were changed by another transaction that has not yet committed, your query waits until that transaction ends and then uses the latest values.

At the start of the transaction you would `SELECT ... FOR SHARE` all the rows that you are planning to update and then proceed with the actual updates.